# adsense question ok?

Tags: support, specific-question

May I ask a question about adsense, specifically how could I get paid something like 10 USD for just one click today? Because normally I never get that much for a click. How much can it vary and what makes the large difference?

Answer (score 5):

We have lots of questions about AdSense.   AdSense is a service that is used by many webmasters.  AdSense questions are on-topic.

You'll have to find a way to phrase your question to be applicable to more than just your situation.   For example instead of asking "Why was this AdSense click 10 USD", you could ask "What accounts for the wide variation in rates paid per click in AdSense"